# One button to navigate and clear collection powerapps

Tags: powerapps

i can't find formula, which allows after press one button, clear collect data and navigate to other screen.
I try:
Navigate(Screen3; ScreenTransition.Fade) And Clear(Collection)
But i have error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use "And", it's only usable for conditions. Instead use a semi-colon between your functions

> Clear(Collection) ; Navigate(Screen3; ScreenTransition.Fade)

You can chain as much functions as you want

Please find it this doc some explanation (in Formula chaining) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/operators

Have a good day